# File upload in PHP not returning error code

Tags: php, file, error-handling, upload

I have a problem when attempting to upload really big files using PHP. I know this has been raised before and I have read many responses, but I have not found a definitive answer.

The basic code I use is posted here: http://design.wildsandwebdesign.co.uk/technical/uploading-files-2.php and I have used this with complete success for letting client upload image files, JPEG, GIF, png etc. The problem arose in allowing users to upload non-displayable files such as .psd files which can be very large.

In php.ini on both my local and remote servers `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`  are set to 128MB. The hidden field MAX_FILE_SIZE in the code has been set to various values during development. The problem is this: If the user selects a file bigger than the  `MAX_FILE_SIZE` but smaller than 128MB,`$_FILES['uploadfile']['error']`  returns an error code of 2 as the PHP documentation says it will. If the file size exceeds 128MB then the upload handling fails altogether with bizarre results.

The “bizarre” results include irrelevant error messages such as “Undefined index: uploadbtn” this being the index of the submit button you have to click to get the error message(!)  This happens with Firefox 26 and with Chrome. Bigger files can crash Firefox altogether which then displays the bug report dialog.

I don't want to upload files larger than 128MB, I just want to handle the situation where a user selects a very large file in some reasonable way. Does anyone know how to do this?

The production code is very much more complicated than the example above but I will happily provide it on request.

......

Comment: Why not put the MAX_FILE_SIZE at 128 MB and validate with AJAX the field with $_FILES['filename']['size'] comparing it with a variable set by you $max_file_size = <<value you want it to be max>> and return an error if it's bigger than that

Comment: The processing code does not run at all, debug code cannot retrieve any values from the $_FILES array when the selected file is > 128MB and I suspect it may not be created at all, but I will certainly follow this up. Thanks.